# how to print checkboxes array in message body of mail function

Tags: php, forms, checkbox

I am doing a mail function in PHP. As  the body of the mail function, I have a table which displays all the posted values including checkboxes.
The message is as follows:

```
$bname = $_POST['$bname'];
$message = Business Name :  
        $bname
```

The above message is in table and Business Name is one td and $bname is another td.
Now I have a chechbox array as

```
$c1 = $_POST['$c1'];
```

I have tried using

```
foreach ($c1 as $c2)   
{  
    echo $c2;  
}
```

The above statement gives me a correct posted values.
But now I have to include this in table of the $message. If I include the full foreach in td, it displays the full foreach as it is. I tried catching the full foreach in one variable, and then put this variable directly in td, but did not get the values.

Please provide me a solution to this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="male">
<input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="female">

$checkboxes = implode(",",$_POST['cbox']);
```

now you can use $checkboxes anywhere in the message

Answer (score 2):

Remove the dollar from `$c1` if your post field is named `c1`:

```
$c1 = $_POST['c1'];
```

Comment: It gives me an error if I remove $ from $c1. I have to display the checkboxes value in table